# Count number of people in each country in SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables:
Table 1:

```
------------------------------
|Country    |Emp Level  |Name|
|-----------|-----------|-----
|UK         |Staff      |A
|US         |Admin Staff|B
|CA         |Staff      |C
|NL         |Admin Staff|D
|MN         |Intern     |E
|IN         |Staff      |F
|UK         |Staff      |G
|US         |Admin Staff|H
------------------------------
```

Table 2:

```
---------------------------------------------
|Level Guid |Level name |Country code       |
|-----------|-----------|-------------------|
|101        |Admin Staff|UK                 |
|102        |Admin Staff|US                 |
|103        |Admin Staff|Global             |
|105        |Staff      |UK                 |
|106        |Staff      |US                 |
|107        |Staff      |Global             |
|108        |Intern     |UK                 |
|109        |Intern     |US                 |
|110        |Intern     |Global             |
---------------------------------------------
```

And result should be:

```
|Level ID   |Level      |Country| Count     |
|105        |Staff      |UK     | 2         |
|102        |Admin Staff|US     | 2         |
|107        |Staff      |CA     | 1         |
|103        |Admin Staff|NL     | 1         |
|110        |Intern     |MN     | 1         |
|107        |Staff      |IN     | 1         |
```

In table 2 any country except US,Uk is considered Global. Note that the countries are counted sepeartely even though in Table 2, all the countries except US, Uk are Global. I have tried a query liek this but it is giving me error `More than 1 value returned in subquery`

```
SELECT country, 
       emp - levels, 
       Count(emp - levels) count, 
       "LevelID"= CASE 
                    WHEN (SELECT level_guid 
                          FROM   table_2 T 
                          WHERE  u.emp - levels = T.level_name 
                                 AND u.country IN ( 'UK', 'US' )) IS NOT NULL 
                  THEN 
                    (SELECT level_guid 
                     FROM   table_2 T 
                     WHERE  u.emp - levels = T.level_name 
                            AND u.country NOT IN ( 'UK', 'US' )) 
                    ELSE (SELECT level_guid 
                          FROM   [DPN_Reporting].dbo.taxonomytermset T 
                          WHERE  u.emp_levels = T.level_name 
                                 AND T.level_name = 'Global') 
                  END 
FROM   table_1 u 
WHERE  emp - levels IS NOT NULL 
       AND emp - levels != '' 
GROUP  BY emp - levels, 
          country 
ORDER  BY Count(emp - levels) DESC
```

Comment: you have rather strange mixup of countries (US, UK) and states (CA, MN, ...). Wouldn't it be more logical to have country and state columns separately?

Comment: @mvp Isn't CA for Canada and MN for maybe another country?

Comment: Please provide your tables in sql format.

Comment: CA - Canada, NL - Netherlands, IN - India, MN.. erm.. Montenegro? Personally, I blame the teachers, the standard of homework questions just aren't what they used to be :)

Comment: MN is Mongolia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
CASE 
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT level_guid 
                FROM   table_2 T 
                WHERE  u.emp - levels = T.level_name 
                AND u.country IN ( 'UK', 'US' )) 
   THEN (SELECT MAX(level_guid)
        FROM   table_2 T 
        WHERE  u.emp - levels = T.level_name 
        AND u.country NOT IN ( 'UK', 'US' )) 
   ELSE (SELECT MAX(level_guid)
        FROM   [DPN_Reporting].dbo.taxonomytermset T 
        WHERE  u.emp_levels = T.level_name 
        AND T.level_name = 'Global') 
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here there are two queries:

```
SELECT T2.[Level Guid] [Level ID], T1.[Emp Level] Level, T1.Country, COUNT(*) Count 
    FROM Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.[Emp Level] = T2.[Level name] 
        AND CASE T1.Country WHEN 'UK' THEN 'UK' WHEN 'US' THEN 'US' ELSE 'Global' END = T2.[Country code]
    GROUP BY T2.[Level Guid], T1.[Emp Level], T1.Country
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18e8f/8

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT T2.[Level Guid] [Level ID], T1.[Emp Level] Level, T1.Country, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table1 T3 WHERE T1.Country = T3.Country) Count
    FROM Table1 T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.[Emp Level] = T2.[Level name] 
        AND CASE T1.Country WHEN 'UK' THEN 'UK' WHEN 'US' THEN 'US' ELSE 'Global' END = T2.[Country code]
```

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/18e8f/7

The first one in `Count` will give the number of persons with the same `T2.[Level Guid], T1.[Emp Level], T1.Country`.

The second one in `Count` will give the number of persons of the same `Country`. Note that I've added a DISTINCT to make the result the same as you.

I think the second one is useless as a query, because you lose the information that there are 2x `UK Staff` and 2x `US Admin Staff` for example.

As a suggestion, please **don't put spaces in the column names!** .

Answer (score 1):

Something like this might work for you:

```
SELECT  [Level Guid], [Level name], Country , COUNT(*) [Count]
FROM dbo.table_1 t1
LEFT JOIN dbo.table_2 t2 ON t2.[Country code] = CASE WHEN t1.Country IN ('UK','US') THEN t1.Country ELSE 'Global' END
    AND t1.[Emp Level] = t2.[Level name]
GROUP BY [Level Guid], [Level name], Country
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c1c25/1)**